# How to get the values of all the elements in an XML into an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, xml

For example :

I have the following XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TEST>
<Name>TESTRUN</Name>
<SyncByte>ff</SyncByte>
<SOM>53</SOM>
<PDADD>7e</PDADD>
<LENLSB>08</LENLSB>
</Test>
```

I would like to get the values from the tags "SyncByte", "SOM", "PADD" and "LENLSB" into a single array. Is there an option within XML to accomplish this?

P.S. There are close to 20+ tags in the XML and not all tags contain values all the time. Hence if there is a single command to get all the values of the XML, then it would be great.

Comment: show something what you have done so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Linq to Xml:

```
    var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
    <Test>
        <Name>TESTRUN</Name>
        <SyncByte>ff</SyncByte>
        <SOM>53</SOM>
        <PDADD>7e</PDADD>
        <LENLSB>08</LENLSB>
    </Test>";

    var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    string[] values = doc.Root.Descendants().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

First:
  your xml formate is wrong , it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TEST>
<Name>TESTRUN</Name>
<SyncByte>ff</SyncByte>
<SOM>53</SOM>
<PDADD>7e</PDADD>
<LENLSB>08</LENLSB>
</TEST> <!--END Tag should same as TEST -->
```

Then you can query them like this:

```
var xml=XDocument.Load("d:\\test.xml");
var list=xml.Descendants("TEST")
            .Select(x=>new
                    {
                        SyncByte=x.Element("SyncByte")==null?"":x.Element("SyncByte").Value,
                        SOM=x.Element("SOM")==null?"":x.Element("SOM").Value,
                        LENLSB=x.Element("LENLSB")==null?"":x.Element("LENLSB").Value
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the child of any parent node through 'XmlElement.ChildNodes' and store it in collection.

for eg :

```
static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            string strFilename = "Input.xml";
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            if (File.Exists(strFilename))
            {
                xmlDoc.Load(strFilename);
                XmlElement elm = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
                XmlNodeList lstVideos = elm.ChildNodes;

                for (int i = 0; i < lstVideos.Count; i++)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}",lstVideos[i].InnerText );
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("The file {0} could not be located",
                                  strFilename);

            Console.WriteLine();
            return 0;
        }
```